# reading oracle .arc files

Tags: database, oracle, archive

we have an Oracle DB that cannot take up any additional insert/update load. Is it possible to extract such commands from the .arc files and update another non-oracle DB so that I can run reports off the new DB? Once that is done, I can reduce the load of all queries and reports from the main DB!

I understand that it is these very .arc files that are used for replicating to another oracle DB and that is what I want to do - except that the target DB is not oracle.

Comment: In a word, no, sorry

Comment: Oracle archive logs are proprietary to Oracle's RDBMS. You'd need to use something like a logminer utility to determine what the archived log has recorded. Replicating DML is not simple, that's why there are products like Quest's Shareplex and Oracle's Goldengate/DataGuard.